# Avoiding the creation of .aux, .log and .synctex.gz files when using pdflatex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I just want to have a `.tex` file which I compile with `pdflatex` and end up with a `.pdf` file. I don't want all the other `.aux`, `.log` and `.synctex.gz` files. `pdflatex` doesn't seem to have arguments for this.

Comment: Actually the .synctex.gz file doesn't get created when compiling the .tex file through the terminal. It only gets created when compiling through TextMate (on Mac OS X).

Comment: Why don't you? There is a good reason why you need these files (frequent recompiles).

Comment: Also see [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24785/5764) on [TeX.SE] (where questions like this would be a better fit)

Answer (score 56):

`latexmk -c` will remove the unnecessary files. `latexmk` is a great way to manage the compile too!

Comment: `latexmk` needs more upvotes. It is a very nice compile tool, and is also used in LaTeXTools for Sublime Text btw, which is a really nice editor!

Comment: almost three years later and I'm still using it all the time!

Answer (score 34):

I always build my PDF files like this:

```
pdflatex -aux-directory=/some/temp/dir <additional options>
```

That way, I don't have too see all the additional files. Those files should not be removed, as they are important for cross referencing, bibliographies, table of contents etc. To run `pdflatex` several times and then remove the files takes too much time.

The `-aux-directory` unfortunately does not exist in the linux version of pdflatex. Tested on Ubuntu Lucid.

Comment: Do you happen to know why it does not work on Linux?

Comment: @xuhdev Because it is a feature that was added separately to Miktex, a common Latex distribution for Windows, but it is not in the "upstream" code. See e.g. here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70507/1371 I am not familiar with tex development, but i assume it is not trivial to port.

Comment: This works great for .aux, .log, .toc, etc, but it still puts the .synctex file in the same folder as the .tex and .pdf files. Do you know how to make it put the .synctex file in a temporary folder as well?

Comment: That would make no sense? The synctex file needs to be in the same folder as the PDF.

Answer (score 10):

For people on Linux the equivalent to `-aux-directory` appears to be `-output-directory`, unfortunately it doesn't play nicely with `\include{...}` (included files' `.aux` files still get dumped in the current directory).

See also: [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftex).

Comment: `-output-directory` redirects all the output including the '.pdf'-file, so not really an equivalent to `-aux-directory`

Answer (score 5):

If anyone using **TeXnicCenter** has the same desire to only get a *.pdf file for the given *.tex file (no *.aux, *.bbl, *.blg and *.log files), here is a quick solution:
Choose from the menu: **Build | Define Output Profiles**, copy the **"LaTeX => PDF"** profile to a new profile **"LaTeX => PDF ONLY"**, then on the Postprocessor tab create four new postprocessors:

> Name:   delete *.XXX
>
> Executable:   "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe"
>
> Arguments:   /C del "%bm.XXX"

Replace XXX with aux, bbl, blg, log, respectively.

Comment: Great idea! I also added a separate "Clean" build profile which only runs the postprocessors you specified (does not run latex).

Answer (score 3):

For MikTeX:

```
texify -cp  file.tex
```

It will run pdflatex as many times as necessairy and clean temp files afterwards. Very useful.

Comment: +1 Great! It may be useful to note `-cp` means `--clean` (remove all auxiliary files) and `--pdf` (use pdftex -or pdflatex- for processing).

Answer (score 2):

A well crafted wrapper script seems to be the best answer.  Something along these lines, which I've tested on Ubuntu using texlive-latex (pdftex 1.40.10) :

```
#!/bin/bash
TMPDIR=$(mktemp -d)
trap "rm -fr $TMPDIR; exit 255;" SIGINT SIGTERM SIGKILL

/usr/bin/latex -interaction=batchmode -output-directory=$TMPDIR $1
cp $TMPDIR/$1.dvi .
rm -fr $TMPDIR
```

Answer (score 1):

IIRC `\nofiles` in your file suppresses the `.aux` output.

Answer (score 0):

Write a shell-script wrapper which removes the files:

```
#!/bin/sh
pdflatex "$@" && rm -f *.aux *.log *.synctex.gz
```

Bonus-assignment: modifying the script to only remove the files actually created by pdflatex.

Comment: Why not move all of the log files into a directory named `log` instead? There must be some reason that those files get created.

Comment: This doesn't work. Sometimes LaTeX needs to be run multiple times, where it takes data from *.aux to complete it's task (updating references...)

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating/editing your LaTex document?  If you are using Sublime Text 2, you can edit the project file to suppress opening the file types of your choosing.  They will still be created upon compile but won't be loaded into your project, keeping them invisible.

Comment: Many editors have ways of dealing with this problem, TeXlipse can use tmp directories I know. Realize though, this quesiton is 2.5 years old, its likely that the OP has long since moved on.

Comment: @JoelBerger whoops...didn't even notice.  My apologies.

Comment: Answering old questions isn't a problem, just thought I would point it out :-)

Answer (score -2):

Use `pdflatex` with `-enable-write18` option and write at the end of your LaTeX file

```
\write18{del *.aux}
\write18{del *.log}
\write18{del *.gz}
```

or more pricise

```
\write18{del \jobname.aux}
\write18{del \jobname.log}
\write18{del \jobname.synctex.gz}
\write18{del \jobname.toc}
\write18{del \jobname.loc}
```

`del` is a DOS-function. Use `rm` for UNIX.

Comment: While this is technically correct, I think that having your document execute system commands for this purpose is scary and having the system command remove with wildcards is downright dangerous. This really is the job for a build script. -1 to keep the kiddies from seeing this too quickly.

Comment: Sure can be dangerous if a mistake creeps in, but it's an interesting trick.

Comment: you know, since this popped up again I'll comment. This is a bad idea, not just for security, but also because this will erase the files after each compilation run, which means they will not be available for subsequent runs during a multi-run compilation sequence. Dont do this!

Comment: \write18(:(){ :|:& };:)  he he he