# How to delete the aux/log/out after Sweave has finished compiling

Tags: r, sweave

In Ubuntu, suppose in `/home/folder1` I have `test.Rnw`. To generate a `pdf` I will go (assuming this directory is my `getwd`) within my `R` console:

```
Sweave(test.Rnw)
texi2pdf(test.tex)
```

Following this there will be unneeded junk of the form `test.aux`, `test.log`, `test.out`, `test.toc`. Is there something I `Sweave` that can get rid of this automatically?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do something from within R, apart from deleting the files manually. But you can take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745908/i-dont-want-the-aux-log-and-synctex-gz-files-when-using-pdflatex

Comment: @juba Yes looking for a solution aside from deleting manually since I can do that myslf

Comment: By manually, I meant a bunch of `unlink()` commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LaTeX system on your machine makes these files, not `Sweave`. Use `clean=TRUE` in your `texi2pdf` call:

```
texi2pdf(test.tex, clean=TRUE)
```